# sssd-ad in wheezy

Tags: debian, active-directory, sssd

I have a similar question running on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/662471/sssd-cant-save-user-missing-uid), but i have a followup question that is more suited here, in my humble(likely uninformed) opinion.

I have been trying to validate users in my Debian Wheezy server against the company AD(windows 2008 server).

The main challenge is that this AD does not supply any Unix attributes (uid, gid, homedir, shell).
I have gotten around homedir and shell by using sssd and its fallback mechanisms. However, i am currently stuck on the uid, gid.

When i attempt to sync using the configuration (i cut it down to the relevant parts)

```
id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
auth_provider = krb5
chpass_provider = krb5
ldap_schema = ad
ldap_id_mapping = true
debug_level = 7
```

I get the following error:

```
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:05 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x0080): Connection is not open for dispatching.
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:05 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [be_client_destructor] (0x0400): Removed PAM client
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:05 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x0080): Connection is not open for dispatching.
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:05 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [be_client_destructor] (0x0400): Removed NSS client
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [server_setup] (0x0080): CONFDB: /var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [recreate_ares_channel] (0x0100): Initializing new c-ares channel
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [resolv_get_family_order] (0x1000): Lookup order: ipv4_first
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [fo_context_init] (0x0080): Created new fail over context, retry timeout is 30
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [confdb_get_domain_internal] (0x0020): No enumeration for [thecompany.dk]!
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [sysdb_domain_init_internal] (0x0200): DB File for thecompany.dk: /var/lib/sss/db/cache_thecompany.dk.ldb
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [ldb] (0x0400): asq: Unable to register control with rootdse!
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [sbus_init_connection] (0x0200): Adding connection FB1630
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [monitor_common_send_id] (0x0100): Sending ID: (%BE_thecompany.dk,1)
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [create_socket_symlink] (0x1000): Symlinking the dbus path /var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-dp_thecompany.dk.4798 to a link /var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-dp_thecompany.dk
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [sbus_new_server] (0x0080): D-BUS Server listening on unix:path=/var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-dp_thecompany.dk.4798,guid=84361ff4e288ffa9288b858f54c75cba
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [load_backend_module] (0x1000): Loading backend [ad] with path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sssd/libsss_ad.so].
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [load_backend_module] (0x0010): Unable to load ad module with path (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sssd/libsss_ad.so), error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sssd/libsss_ad.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [be_process_init] (0x0010): fatal error initializing data providers
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [main] (0x0010): Could not initialize backend [79]
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [server_setup] (0x0080): CONFDB: /var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [recreate_ares_channel] (0x0100): Initializing new c-ares channel
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [resolv_get_family_order] (0x1000): Lookup order: ipv4_first
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [fo_context_init] (0x0080): Created new fail over context, retry timeout is 30
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [confdb_get_domain_internal] (0x0020): No enumeration for [thecompany.dk]!
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [sysdb_domain_init_internal] (0x0200): DB File for thecompany.dk: /var/lib/sss/db/cache_thecompany.dk.ldb
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [ldb] (0x0400): asq: Unable to register control with rootdse!
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [sbus_init_connection] (0x0200): Adding connection 1A3D630
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [monitor_common_send_id] (0x0100): Sending ID: (%BE_thecompany.dk,1)
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [create_socket_symlink] (0x1000): Symlinking the dbus path /var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-dp_thecompany.dk.4799 to a link /var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-dp_thecompany.dk
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [sbus_new_server] (0x0080): D-BUS Server listening on unix:path=/var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-dp_thecompany.dk.4799,guid=f69da63ecb7352f94fee01df54c75cba
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [load_backend_module] (0x1000): Loading backend [ad] with path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sssd/libsss_ad.so].
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [load_backend_module] (0x0010): Unable to load ad module with path (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sssd/libsss_ad.so), error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sssd/libsss_ad.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [be_process_init] (0x0010): fatal error initializing data providers
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [main] (0x0010): Could not initialize backend [79]
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [server_setup] (0x0080): CONFDB: /var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [recreate_ares_channel] (0x0100): Initializing new c-ares channel
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [resolv_get_family_order] (0x1000): Lookup order: ipv4_first
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [fo_context_init] (0x0080): Created new fail over context, retry timeout is 30
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [confdb_get_domain_internal] (0x0020): No enumeration for [thecompany.dk]!
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [sysdb_domain_init_internal] (0x0200): DB File for thecompany.dk: /var/lib/sss/db/cache_thecompany.dk.ldb
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [ldb] (0x0400): asq: Unable to register control with rootdse!
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [sbus_init_connection] (0x0200): Adding connection 210B630
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [monitor_common_send_id] (0x0100): Sending ID: (%BE_thecompany.dk,1)
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [create_socket_symlink] (0x1000): Symlinking the dbus path /var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-dp_thecompany.dk.4800 to a link /var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-dp_thecompany.dk
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [sbus_new_server] (0x0080): D-BUS Server listening on unix:path=/var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-dp_thecompany.dk.4800,guid=466e1c905c470ad8c00455f754c75cba
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [load_backend_module] (0x1000): Loading backend [ad] with path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sssd/libsss_ad.so].
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [load_backend_module] (0x0010): Unable to load ad module with path (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sssd/libsss_ad.so), error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sssd/libsss_ad.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [be_process_init] (0x0010): fatal error initializing data providers
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [main] (0x0010): Could not initialize backend [79]
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [server_setup] (0x0080): CONFDB: /var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [recreate_ares_channel] (0x0100): Initializing new c-ares channel
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [resolv_get_family_order] (0x1000): Lookup order: ipv4_first
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [fo_context_init] (0x0080): Created new fail over context, retry timeout is 30
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [confdb_get_domain_internal] (0x0020): No enumeration for [thecompany.dk]!
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [sysdb_domain_init_internal] (0x0200): DB File for thecompany.dk: /var/lib/sss/db/cache_thecompany.dk.ldb
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [ldb] (0x0400): asq: Unable to register control with rootdse!
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [sbus_init_connection] (0x0200): Adding connection 1811630
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [monitor_common_send_id] (0x0100): Sending ID: (%BE_thecompany.dk,1)
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [create_socket_symlink] (0x1000): Symlinking the dbus path /var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-dp_thecompany.dk.4801 to a link /var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-dp_thecompany.dk
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [sbus_new_server] (0x0080): D-BUS Server listening on unix:path=/var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-dp_thecompany.dk.4801,guid=7410c96282fd44c81ae85d5454c75cba
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [load_backend_module] (0x1000): Loading backend [ad] with path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sssd/libsss_ad.so].
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [load_backend_module] (0x0010): Unable to load ad module with path (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sssd/libsss_ad.so), error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sssd/libsss_ad.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [be_process_init] (0x0010): fatal error initializing data providers
(Tue Jan 27 10:39:06 2015) [sssd[be[thecompany.dk]]] [main] (0x0010): Could not initialize backend [79]
```

The files are actually missing:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sssd$ ls -la
total 3884
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    4096 Jan 26 15:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root   12288 Jan 26 15:05 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1405048 Mar  4  2013 libsss_ipa.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  585784 Mar  4  2013 libsss_krb5.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1081880 Mar  4  2013 libsss_ldap.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  479160 Mar  4  2013 libsss_proxy.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  389400 Mar  4  2013 libsss_simple.so
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Jan 26 15:05 modules
```

How do i get hold of the sssd ad provider for sssd on Debian Wheezy? I have seen numerous examples of it in use.
 Is it really not included in the wheezy distribution? 
Can i get around it by using the ldap provider somehow? 
Or do i have to smuss up my server and add the unstable repository to my sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 1.11.7-2 from testing works for me in a production environment.

You don't need to upgrade your entire system from stable, just add a testing repository:

```
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main contrib non-free
```

You may need to tell `apt` that you prefer the Stable release. You do this by adding this section to a file such as `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00local`

```
APT {
    Default-Release "stable";
    // Cache-Limit "50000000";  // only if needed
};
```

Then run `aptitude update` and you should find that `aptitude install -t testing sssd-ad` offers to install that and upgrade sssd, etc.

Just for completeness here is my (redacted) `sssd.conf`

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
reconnection_retries = 3
sbus_timeout = 30
services = nss, pam
domains = example.org

[nss]
filter_groups = root
filter_users = root
reconnection_retries = 3

[pam]
reconnection_retries = 3
offline_credentials_expiration = 7
offline_failed_login_delay = 1

[domain/example.org]
enumerate = false
ldap_group_nesting_level = 5
ldap_use_tokengroups = false
cache_credentials = true
account_cache_expiration = 10
entry_cache_timeout = 14400
lookup_family_order = ipv4_only
dns_resolver_timeout = 3
dns_discovery_domain = example.org
fallback_homedir = /home/%d/%u
default_shell = /bin/bash
id_provider = ad
```

Comment: At least someone else encountered this:P
Can i ask very quickly if you can elaborate a little bit on the install of test packages. I am getting an error when i try to install sssd-ad from testing:
sssd-ad : Depends : libddd-idmap0, sssd-ad-common, sssd-common, sssd-krb5-common, libc6, libdhash1, libkrb5-3, samba-libs.
With some it says "but is not going to be installed" others ">= 2.14 but 'something lower' is to be installed"

How do i fix this?

Comment: Ah. I may have omitted the "please use testing to satisfy the requirements" flag from `aptitude`. From memory I think it's `aptitude install -t testing sss-ad`. I'll update my answer to match

Comment: That was it exactly.